# Is it possible to write a constant value to a binary file directly?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite, stdio

I know that

```
fwrite(&variable,sizeof(datatype),<count>,<filepointer>);
```

writes data onto a 
binary file. But what if I want to write the character 'c' directly into the binary file (without using a buffer variable). I can't put,

```
 fwrite(&'c',sizeof(datatype),<count>,<filepointer>);
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use putc or fputc (both have the same signature):

```
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

If you're interested in putc vs fputc check the comments below, they know it better than me :)

Comment: Or `putc`, which might be a bit faster.

Comment: my curiosity: what's the difference between putc & fputc?

Comment: @anishsane they are functionally identical, it's just a matter of implementation

Comment: ^^Yes, understood that from prototype, but is fputc a wrapper around putc, or completely different implementation? How is it _optimized_.

Comment: @anishsane I have no idea about that, sorry :)

Comment: hmm... because having 2 functions, with same prototype, same functionality, in same library, but different level of optimization is odd.

Comment: @anishsane yeah, I guess it happened because of compatibility issues or something like that

Comment: @anishsane: according to the C standard, `fputc` and `putc` are functionally identical but the the latter *may* be implemented as a macro (so its implementation will be inlined) and it may evaluate `stream` more than once. So unless that's a problem, or you need a function pointer, `putc` should be preferred over `fputc`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `putc` got broken efficiency-wise with the introduction of multithreading. Instead of being a macro that just takes the next character directly from the stdio buffer (after, if necessary, calling a stdio function to fill it), `putc` nowadays expands to a function that also locks and unlocks the file object. To get the true efficiency of `putc` as intended by the authors of C, Linux provides `putc_unlocked`.

Comment: @user4815162342: So I guess that fputc locks stdin as well?

Comment: @BlackBear `fputc` doesn't make much sense with standard input, but `fgetc` on stdin will protect the integrity of the data structure by locking it. All stdio functions on POSIX platforms lock the stream, as part of their MT-safety contract. The _unlocked variants are provided for efficiency, and efficiency gain is most noticable with macros such as `putc`, `putchar`, `getc`, and `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, you cannot get the address of a constant. So no, you can’t.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fwrite("c",sizeof(datatype),<count>,<filepointer>);
```

e.g.

```
fwrite("c",1,1,fileptr);
```

NOTE: I have not tested it myself. But I suspect that this should work.

Adding after comment by Eric:

```
fwrite((char []){'c'}, 1, 1, fileptr);
```

The advantage of ^^this approach is, just like char, you can insert an integer or any other standard data type also.

Comment: putc looks like optimized solution.

Comment: The second argument to your suggested code looks wrong.  The OP wants to write a single char so the size of the write should be 1.

Comment: If it bothers you to waste a null character after the string literal, you can also do `fwrite((char []){'c'}, 1, 1, stdout)`.

Comment: ^^ I had just thought about this, after I left for home :-)